# Building Python 2.7.9 on a machine where Python 2.7.5 is the system default

Tags: python, python-2.7, build, shared-libraries, autoconf

In CentOS 7, Python 2.7.5 is the default, and I'm trying to install a standalone installation of 2.7.9 to /usr/local/stow/python-2.7.9 from source.  I noticed, however, when running "make test", some of the output seems to indicate that my version is trying to rely on the system version:

```
[113/400] test_distutils
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/compileall.py", line 16, in <module>
    import struct
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/struct.py", line 1, in <module>
    from _struct import *
ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_struct.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
```

My version of Python is meant to be 100% independent of the system version.  How can I configure/make/make install this thing and force it to ignore the pre-existing Python 2.7.5 files?  I set my LD_LIBRARY_PATH to my build directory's lib directory, but that didn't help (still found /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_struct.so before finding mine).

(I don't care about this specific error about the wrong ELF class, I'm solely interested in getting my build to completely ignore the system Python).

Comment: why do you want to? Why not use a virtualenv if you want an isolated install?

Comment: you *really* should use a virtual environment for this. [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-python-2-7-6-and-3-3-3-on-centos-6-4) is a pretty decent reference on how to for red hat

Comment: It's not for my personal use, we're setting up a server for our users and the specifications that have been requested of me is to set up an install of 2.7.9 separate from 2.7.5 that will be globally accessible via NFS for all users.  Using virtualenv makes sense and ideally, we'd just have all users set up their own virtualenvs for all their projects.  But we don't offer unlimited disk quota, and when told about virtualenv to manage their own environments, our researchers/academics/etc. have a, "I can't be bothered to do this, you're supposed to install and manage my stuff" attitude.

Comment: The tl;dr is virtualenv is an amazing tool for an individual developer, but it's not the route I'd like to take for this project.  As for, "why install a separate 2.7.9 instead of supplement the existing 2.7.5 installation with packages in a PYTHONPATH," (an option we considered) there's not enough room in these comments to explain our internal reasons.  Should I take the lack of answers so far to mean that what I want to do simply isn't possible?

Comment: Did you find a fix? Using rpaths fixes it . It has been 10 months since this question was asked , so I am not sure if you found a fix or not. Comment back if you are still looking for a fix.

Comment: I saw this question after posting mine (possibly related). Does anyone on this thread have an answer? I do intend to use virtualenv, but need to fix this issue first.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37345044/issue-with-installing-python-2-7-8-alongside-2-7-5-on-rhel-7-2